# Radicación usando Rstudio

Tags: r

Del siguiente vector:

```
      Serpent <- c (14, 15, 16, -10, 9, -4)
```

y a través de la siguiente función:

```
      Piton <- function(x) x**(1/3)
```

se intenta conseguir la raíz cubica del vector antes mencionado. 
El problema es que para los números negativos arroja NaN.

¿Cómo puedo mejorar la función para obtener todos los valores de la raíz cubica del vector, tanto positivos como negativos?

Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Es básicamente un problema del orden de precedencia de los operadores en **R**, esto está documentado en [esta FAQ](http://www.hep.by/gnu/r-patched/r-faq/R-FAQ_84.html)

Para ver más claro el problema

```
-8^(1/3) == (-8)^(1/3) # NA 
-8^(1/3) == -(8^(1/3)) # TRUE
```

El reemplazo de tu función podría ser algo así:

```
Piton2 <- function(x){
    return(sign(x) * abs(x)**(1/3))
}
```